# Error when trying to run an flutter app as windows app: custom build exited with code 9084

Tags: windows, flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When i try to run my flutter app using the Start Debugging option on VSCode i receive the below error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
main.dart:1
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'D:\Flutter\listinha\app\build\windows\CMakeFiles\cde8ac8d4a075c23cd97a549ffa329b3\flutter_windows.dll.rule;D:\Flutter\listinha\app\build\windows\CMakeFiles\8e0ee5c513e4a2076625cceb68497287\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 9084. [D:\Flutter\listinha\app\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
Exited (sigterm)
```

but when i execute the command `flutter run -d Windows` the app runs normally...

What i need to do to be able to run the app from Start Debugging ?

`flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.819], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.7.5 on channel stable at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c07f788888 (6 days ago), 2023-02-22 17:52:33 -0600
    • Engine revision 0f359063c4
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33-ext4, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33414.496
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)

[√] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.819]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5481.178

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Below are the results when **Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor** command from the VS Code command palette is executed:

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.819], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.7.5 on channel stable at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c07f788888 (7 days ago), 2023-02-22 17:52:33 -0600
    • Engine revision 0f359063c4
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33-ext4, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33414.496
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)

[√] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.819]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5481.178

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
exit code 0
```

So i have a diff when running from terminal and when running from command palette:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33-ext4, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
```

When in terminal, if i run the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses` i got `All SDK package licenses accepted.` as result but if i run the **Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor** command from the VS Code command palette i still have the issue.

Comment: can you include your `flutter doctor -v` output

Comment: it is running on debug mode, add some breakpoint

Comment: same result, its getting the same error

Comment: Can you try running Flutter Doctor using the **Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor** command from the VS Code command palette and see whether it differs from the output at the terminal? If that doesn't reveal anything, please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code and we can troubleshoot further.

Comment: Hi @DannyTuppeny! When i run the **Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor** from VS Code command palette i have an issue with android license status. I've updated the main topic with the output and some comments

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho could you try running `flutter run -d Windows --machine --start-paused -v` from the terminal to see whether that fails in the same way as it is from VS Code? You could also file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code with the details here, it might be easier to debug where comments aren't so restricted.